# I need to remove items from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, viewstate

I am making a program that takes user input and populates that into a list.  That part is working great.  However the user needs the ability to edit or delete his/her input.  I cannot figure out how to remove an item from the list.  Here is the code for populating the list:

```
[Serializable]
class Recipient
{
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string MInit { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Custom { get; set; }
    public string CardType { get; set; }
} protected void btnToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateInput("Card Information"))
    { SetUI("Your Shopping Cart"); }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    Recipient recipients = new Recipient();

    List<string> FName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> MInit = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> LName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> Suffix = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> Amount = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> Message = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> Custom = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
    List<string> CardType = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];

    if (FName == null && MInit == null && LName == null && Suffix == null && Amount == null &&
            Message == null && Custom == null && CardType == null)
    {
        FName = new List<string>();
        MInit = new List<string>();
        LName = new List<string>();
        Suffix = new List<string>();
        Amount = new List<string>();
        Message = new List<string>();
        Custom = new List<string>();
        CardType = new List<string>();
    }

    recipients.Fname = txtFName.Text;
    recipients.MInit = txtMInit.Text;
    recipients.Lname = txtLName.Text;
    recipients.Suffix = ddlSuffix1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    recipients.Amount = txtAmount.Text;
    recipients.Message = ddlMessage.SelectedItem.ToString();
    recipients.Custom = txtCustom.Text;
    recipients.CardType = lblImage.Text;
    FName.Add(recipients.Fname);
    MInit.Add(recipients.MInit);
    LName.Add(recipients.Lname);
    Suffix.Add(recipients.Suffix);
    Amount.Add(recipients.Amount);
    Message.Add(recipients.Message);
    Custom.Add(recipients.Custom);
    CardType.Add(recipients.CardType);
    ViewState["recipientList"] = FName;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = MInit;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = LName;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = Suffix;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = Amount;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = Message;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = Custom;
    ViewState["recipientList"] = CardType;

    if (FName.Count == 1 && MInit.Count == 1 && LName.Count == 1 && Suffix.Count == 1)
    {
        lblCartName.Text = FName[0] + " " + MInit[0] + " " + LName[0] + " " + Suffix[0];
        lnkEdit1.Visible = true;
    }

    if (Amount.Count == 1 && Message.Count == 1 && Custom.Count == 1)
    {
        lblCartAmount.Text = "$" + Amount[0] + ".00";
        if (txtCustom.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            lblCartMessage.Text = Message[0];
        }
        else
        {
            lblCartMessage.Text = Custom[0];
        }
    }
```

Yes there is more to it but anyways, once the user clicks the next button then a summary is displayed to the user with all input information.  There is also two linkbuttons on the form that gives the user the choice of editing or deleting.  I have tried variations of:

FName.Remove(recipients.fname); and FName.RemoveAt(0);for example and none of these have worked.  So that is my problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You're overwriting the same element in `ViewState` by calling `ViewState["recipientList"] = blah`

Comment: this example gave me headache

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons for this, but wouldn't it be friendlier to create `List<recipients>` than individual lists of each field?

Comment: Sorry for the headache, This code is for a gift card application and the user will be able to add up to five cards so, unfortunately, the individual lists are needed.  So far the app is pushing 900 lines of code with over 1100 lines for the html, so yes, it is a big headache.

Comment: @Chris [`ReSharper`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) would tell you to use `var` instead of `List<string>` every time.

Comment: @Chris, Are you SURE these lists need to be stored separately? Is it possible for me to enter 3 first names, 2 last names, 4 messages, 1 custom and 5 card types?  Unless there is some reason you would do that, your issue is GREATLY simplified by doing a list of recipients.

Comment: With the exception of Suffix and Middle initial, all fields are required.  Basically the purchaser adds the info of people that they want to buy a gift card for.  With what Rich and Silva suggested made my program run perfectly for adding recipients.  The problem is the edit button.  Somehow I need to call the list from the btnToCart to the edit button when the edit button is clicked and then remove the necessary items from the list.  I am probably making this sound more confusing than it really is.

Comment: If the data that needs to be entered should be related together, PLEASE don't add them as separate lists. With your current architecture, you have no way other than index to say that "Chris","Porter","Visa","$50" should be together and not mixed with "Brad","M","MC","$100".  If you stored the strings in a single class and kept each instance of that class in a list, you'd know for sure which are related.  That prevents potentials for a string being mismatched with other strings and ended up with corrupt data.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have also come to that conclusion after much trial and mostly error.  However, I have figured it out and now when the user clicks edit the previous panel of the website is visible with the appropriate data in the input fields.  So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Like @rich.okelly wrote you overwrite your ViewState:
Use something like this:

```
List<string> FName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListFName"];
List<string> MInit = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListMInit"];
List<string> LName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListLName"];
List<string> Suffix = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListSuffix"];
List<string> Amount = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListAmount"];
List<string> Message = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListMessage"];
List<string> Custom = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListCustom"];
List<string> CardType = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListCardType"];
```

Comment: Thank you Slava and Rich.  I did make the changes as you suggested and I see how this works a lot better.  However, I still cannot remove items from the list when the Edit button is clicked.  Any thoughts or directions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: I juust don't understand something, I assume you do something like that: `List<string> FName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientListFName"]; FName.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: I have actually figured it out.  I did not know that ViewState could be called anywhere in my programming.  So, I was able to call it in my edit button and populate the appropriate input fields as needed.  Thank you for your help though.